# writing single-storey ɑ in Gnuplot graph title?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, symbols

How can I write single-storey ɑ (The first letter in English) in Gnuplot graph title?
I am always get "a" (double-story) in Gnuplot plot title?

Answer (score 2):

Suggesting to use the Greek letter alpha "ɑ" is not a good solution.

The correct answer is that the shape of the "a" glyph is dependent on the font, not the encoding.  Unicode codepoints only specify what character is to be drawn, not what shape it has.

Comment: Yes. you are right! But,  how can I write literally single-storey version of 'a' in gnuplot graph title?

Comment: @Martin: You must use a font which has the desired shape. [Futura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futura_(typeface)) is one example. Some fonts only provide that glyph via an OpenType "stylistic alternative" font feature, which, however, cannot be accessed from withint gnuplot.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the `terminal` you want to use, but probably the most straightforward solution would be to use proper encoding and paste the required [character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0251/index.htm) directly:

```
set encoding utf8
set term wxt font "Times,12"
set title 'ɑ'
plot x
```

EDIT:

the special character `ɑ` can be also specified (for example in the interactive Gnuplot console) in terms of its UTF8 representation (two octal numbers) as:

```
set title '\311\221'
```

Comment: At the third line, how can I write 'ɑ' in Ubuntu 16.04 terminal?

Comment: @Martin either copy-paste it from here or use Ctrl+Shift+U then 0251 and Enter... :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used your commands. However, my plot appeared without any title! It seems I have some problem with line 3 about 'ɑ' since when I change it, then I get the another title again!

Comment: @Martin I see, you are trying to type it into Gnuplot directly? Might be better to save it as a file, e.g., `test.gpl` and then in Gnuplot `load 'test.gpl'`

Comment: @Martin in the interactive Gnuplot console, it might be necessary to specify the character in terms of its UTF8 representation as `set title '\311\221'` - here the two octal numbers correspond to the hex representation `0xc9 0x91`of the character (works also when saved as a script)

Comment: %!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
         ^
         "test.gpl", line 1: invalid command

I got this error when I tried to load saved figure via ubuntu terminal

Comment: As Ethan noted in his answer: U+0251 is not an "a", but a phonetic symbol. It can happen, that the respective glyph provided by the font is similar to a single-storey a, but not necessarily. And depending on the use case it might be misleading to use a wrong unicode code point.

Comment: @Christoph thank you for the clarification - appearances can be indeed deceiving... :)

Comment: I know, such fundamental font things are my daily work

Answer (score 0):

I only use lubunutu and do not use ubunutu.
In lubuntu CharacterMap utility exists and it can be used from accessory category.
On ubuntu, the same tool exists.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CharacterMap

I could copy and paste Lattin Small Letter alpha "ɑ" to terminal.
(Note that is not literally single-storey version of a).
As Ethan wrote use of Lattin Small Letter alpha "ɑ" is not correct in literal sense but I think this is possible workaround.

Correct solution is use font with single-storey a like Futura font. 
Free Futura font seem to be available from

http://www.webpagepublicity.com/free-fonts-f4.html#Free%20Fonts